# Does thread has limit to use the network bandwidth?

Tags: multithreading, network-programming

I heard there is some limitation for a single thread to use network bandwidth? if this is true, is this the reason to use multithread programming to achieve the maximum bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to use multithreading for network tasks is that one thread might be waiting for a response from the remote server. Creating multiple threads can help you having at least one thread downloading from different requests at one time.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for issuing more than one network request at a time, (either implicitly with user threads, or implicitly with kernel threads and asynchronous callbacks), is that the effects of network latency can be be minimised.  Latency can have a large effect.  A web connection, for example, needs a DNS lookup first, then a TCP 3-way connect, then some data transfer and finally a 4-way close.  If the page size is small and the bandwidth large compared with the latency, most time is spent waiting for protocol exchanges.

So, if you are crawling multiple servers, a multithreaded design is hugely faster even on a single-core machine.  If you are downloading a single video file from one server, not so much..